# RegEx.Test returns always false

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The problem is that when I try to test it it returns always false. Do you have any idea why?

```
$('MyInput').mouseout(function () {
    alert($('MyInput').val()); // it is  "яяqqåå"
    alert(/^[\p{L}0-9\s\.\\\/\-]{2,20}$/.test($('MyInput').val()));
});
```

Comment: Please, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode

Comment: Yes, but I want to accept all cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Javascript regex doesn't support `\p{L}`

even this returns false:

```
/^\p{L}+/.test('a');
```

You can use this blanket unicode range to match your input text:

```
/^[\u0000-\uffff\d\s.\\\/-]{2,20}$/.test('яяqqåå');
//=> returns true
```

Comment: Then how to include all letters from all languages? Because from what I saw \p{L} does that. p.s. I use in in C# valiadation

Comment: Above regex will definitely match cyrillic alphabets but you can also use `/^[\u0000-\u5500\d\s.\\\/-]{2,20}$/.test('яяqqåå');` for matching only cyrillic/english alphabets.

Comment: i also need scandinavian and east-west europe

Comment: But this one allow me everything. I want to restrict symbols.

Comment: In Javascript you will have to use unicode ranges for each set. For example just to match `cyrillic ` you can use `[\u0400-\u5500]` range and this will return true: `/^[\u0400-\u5500\d\s.\\\/-]{2,20}$/.test('яя');`